# SQL Query Two table with same columns names into one table

Tags: sql

I have two tables with the same columns names and I need to "join" them to be just one table.
here is an example:
Table1:

| Username | Product Name |
| --- | --- |
| User1 | Product1 |
| User2 | Product2 |

Table2:

| Username | Product Name |
| --- | --- |
| User1 | Product2 |
| User2 | Product1 |
| User3 | Product1 |

And I need a third table to be like that:

| Username | Product Name |
| --- | --- |
| User1 | Product1 |
| User1 | Product2 |
| User2 | Product1 |
| User2 | Product2 |
| User3 | Product1 |

I don't think it's complicated but I really not see how to manage it and I'm completely stuck. Also, I'm learning.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you want `union all`:

```
select username, productname
from table1
union all
select username, productname
from table2;
```

You are not trying to match values in columns, so `join` is not really appropriate.  You just want to combine the two tables into a single set of rows.